# Wrapping your terraform root modules in another module

Tags: terraform

Is it a bad practice to wrap your terraform root modules (dir where you run terraform plan) in another module?

for example:

```
dev/base
  main.tf

dev/databases
  main.tf
```

dev/base/main.tf

```
module "data-science" {  << inside this module i would setup s3 buckets, iam roles, etc with publicly available tf modules
 ...
 ...
}
```

dev/databases/main.tf

```
module "databases" {  << inside this module i would setup mysql, postgres with publicly available tf modules
 ...
 ...
}
```

My reason for this is that I would like to be able to create other environments with as little copying/pasting/modifying of the root modules code as much as possible, wrapping the contents of each root module in another module seems to keep this as dry as possible.

Is this a good/bad idea?

---

Update:

To clarify, this what what I may see this in a root module

dev/main.tf

```
module "ec2-instance" {
  cpu = 1
  mem = 1
}

module "iam-role" {
}

module "security-group" {
}

data "iam-policy {
}
```

You often times end up with multiple modules, data sources, etc. this could grow large.

Say I want to replicate this setup in another environment. I end up copying dev/main.tf to another environment and just searching through the  main.tf and making modifications to things to make it fit the environment.

to keep it more dry and more easily deployable, would this make sense. wrapping all the modules above into a parent module.

dev/main.tf

```
module "my-root-module-wrapper" {
  ec2_cpu = 1
  ec2_cpu = 2
}
```

Now if I want to deploy my a new environment, i'm just copying the calling of my root module wrapper that calls all the other terraform. this seems cleaner.

Thought is that all terraform that would otherwise go into a root module instead should now go in "my-root-module-wrapper" instead. making it easier and more DRY to deploy to different environments.

Comment: You could just define child modules, and invoke them as many times as you wish in the root module. You could even use `for_each`.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "wrapping". It appears that you are declaring modules inside your root module config. This is both common and normal.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE for the responses. I updated my post above to add more clarity.

Comment: @MattSchuchard ^

Comment: In that case, you should just write common module & override it per environment with [tfvars](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/variables). No need to keep on changing the *.tf config files per environment.

Comment: For this version of the question, it sounds like you want Terraform Workspaces.

Comment: @harshavmb your reference to a "common" module, that would be like my "my-root-module-wrapper" example above right?

Comment: @MattSchuchard that's a good idea. do you know of any downsides of using terraform workspaces over using my example "my-root-module-wrapper" above?

Comment: In general you would probably want to prefer a native and supported solution developed by the vendor to assist with your use case described above over a custom solution you need to create yourself. Other than that, the other clear advantage with workspaces is significantly less repeated code.

Comment: agreed, thanks.